# strange css behavior in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, dojo

I'm facing a strange behavior in internet-explorer-7.
after setting/resetting a global css-style-class the layout seems broken.  the problem can be reproduced using the following [html-file](http://pastehtml.com/view/b78snbhm6.html). after clicking the button, the table's font-family changes. the js-code just sets a style-class on the body-tag, and removes it again.

it seems, that the `.dijitInputField input.dijitReset`-selector is applied to the `<td>`.

can anybody explain this behavior to me?

**EDIT** as requested, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gerpres/jqSgU/2/) is the jsfiddle-presentation - but it cannot be used to reproduce the error since a doctype is added automatically

Comment: I'd suggest you use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for code snippets and demo pages.

Comment: how can I create a quirks-mode-page in jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not sure you can. But I was talking more about the presentation purposes and not for testing in a specific browser. There is a draft feature, but it's only for registered users.

You cold try to precede DOCTYPE tag with some comment and see if it helps - as it would in IE. EDIT: I am saying "try" because JSFiddle adds doctype automatically.

Comment: if you're using quirksmode, then that is your problem. Seriously, quirksmode was added to IE6 as a way of providing backward compatibility with IE5. If you don't need to support IE5, then you really shouldn't be using quirksmode any more. (if you *do* need to support IE5, then you should have run away screaming long ago already!)

Answer (score 1):

You must use DOCTYPE for your (x)html documents. It always saves the time and allows to avoid facing strange problems/bugs especially in IE.

Comment: I know that it's recommended to set the doctype to avoid quirks-mode - in fact would solve this problem too ;-) but I have to handle legacy code which I cannot change any more

Comment: @Gerhard: quirksmode is the problem. If you can't get rid of the need to use quirksmode, then you're going to struggle to get rid of the problem. Simple as that, sorry. This answer is the correct solution, even if it's not the answer you wanted to hear.